# MySQL connection's close() keeps connection active for RemoveAbandonedTimeout value?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

I m using mysql connection pooling with max active connections 250 and setRemoveAbandonedTimeout 300 seconds. When I run queries > 250, I start getting this error: "Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:250; busy:250; idle:0; lastwait:60000]."

After executing query I do close ResultSet, Statement and Connection used to execute the query.

Is there anything I am missing in my setup or it is the way it should behave and I need to manage connections?

For debugging I've put some checks to avoid the above error. Here is the source code:

Pool properties:

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();


            p.setUrl(dbUrl+path+"?autoReconnect=true");
            p.setUsername(username);
            p.setPassword(password);
            p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+path+"?autoReconnect=true");
            p.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            p.setJmxEnabled(true);
            p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
            p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
            p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
            p.setTestOnReturn(false);
            p.setValidationInterval(30000);
            p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
            p.setMaxActive(250);
            p.setInitialSize(10);
            p.setMaxWait(60000);
            p.setMaxAge(1);
            p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(300);
            p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
            p.setMinIdle(10);
            p.setLogAbandoned(false);
            p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
            p.setFairQueue(true);
            p.setAbandonWhenPercentageFull(80);
            p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
            datasource = new DataSource();
            datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
```

Get Statement:

```
private Statement getStatement() throws SQLException
{
    Connection connection  = datasource.getConnection();
    return connection.createStatement();
}
```

Execute Select Query:

```
public ResultSet ExecuteSelectQuery(String sql) throws Exception 
{   
    System.out.println(" QUERY: "+sql );
    System.out.println(" ACTIVE CONNECTIONS :" + datasource.getActive());
    QueriesCount.incrementAndGet(); 
    while(datasource.getActive() > 240){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("WAITING FOR CONNECTION " +datasource.getActive());
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    return  getStatement().executeQuery(sql);
}
```

Release resources :

```
public void CloseResultSet(ResultSet rs) 
{
    try
    {
        if(rs!=null)
        {
            Statement s = rs.getStatement();

            if(s!=null)
            {
                Connection c =  s.getConnection();
                s.close();
                rs.close();
                try{
                    if(c!= null)
                        c.close();
                    c = null;
                    s = null;
                    rs = null;
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    PALogger.ERROR(e);
                }
            }
            else{                   
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Query Count " + QueriesCount.get() + " " + this.path);
    }

}
```

Comment: None of this has anything to do with MySQL. It is all about the properties of the undisclosed connection pool you're using. It looks like one of the various Apache pools, but you need to tell us.

Comment: The way you handle connections is unnecessarily complex and makes a lot of assumptions about the way the statement and result set wrappers of the connection pool work. I don't think it is surprising that this code could leak connections the way it does. Also part of the code you use tries to do what your connection pool already does for you.

Comment: @EJP I am using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes it is complex and it happened bcz we wanted to use this as a library shared between all our products. I am not sure if ResultSet returns the same connection and statement objects which was used to create it. If not then there is absolutely a leak and connections wont be closed.

Comment: Especially with the introduction of try-with-resources in Java 7, there should be no reason to write this type of code.

Comment: In my case, if I return ResultSet, how should I close the connection. try-with-resources will close only resultset, not the connection.

Comment: Is it a good practice, if I use a single connection instance from the pool for all the SELECT queries and create a new connection instance everytime for other queries and close them right there after execution? That way I don't have to close connection each time for SELECT queries.